# PWM signal with cat /dev/urandom | bzip2 > /dev/null command

Tags: bspwm

I am using a C program to generate a pwm on Zybo board, and I want to apply CPU load using `cat /dev/urandom | bzip2 > /dev/null`.

How can this command be executed at the same time with C code ?